# NULL pointer during ATL Dialog WindowProc

Tags: c++, windows, atl

I'm unfamiliar with ATL/Win32 UI programming and I'm trying to fix an access violation which occurs when I close an ATL dialog.

The main window has the following message map:

```
   BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CLOSE, OnClose)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_EXIT, OnExit)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_LOGON, OnLogon)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_LOGOFF, OnLogoff)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_HELP, OnHelp)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_ABOUT, OnAbout)     
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_DATANETSETTINGS, OnConfigure)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_POPUP_TRANSFERSTATUS, OnTransferStatus)
        // etc...
```

OnTransferStatus launches a modal dialog:

```
LRESULT OnTransferStatus(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
    HWND hc;
    hc = FindWindow(NULL, L"MyApp Transfer Status");
    if(hc)
    {
        ::ShowWindow(hc, SW_RESTORE);
        ::SetForegroundWindow(hc);
    }
    else
    {
        CStatusPopup dlg; 
        dlg.DoModal(); // <-- Here
```

The `CStatusPopup` is simply one of these: `class CStatusPopup : public CAxDialogImpl<CStatusPopup>{...}`

When I close the StatusPopup window, I end up in the popup windows message map and this function runs:

```
LRESULT OnClose(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled) 
{
    EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
    return 0;
}
```

EndDialog should cleanly close down the dialog window.  However I appear to be getting a NULL hwnd being passed to the dialog's WindowProc.  This happens deep in ATL/Win32 code underneath the blocking DoModal call.  Can anyone suggest how I can debug where the message came from that passed the NULL hwnd?

The crash is here:

```
00000000`001de6f0 00000000`7741c3c1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`0081d1d0 00000000`00000001 : MyApp_Tray!ATL::CWindowImplBaseT<WTL::CEditT<ATL::CWindow>,ATL::CWinTraits<1442840576,0> >::WindowProc+0x81 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwin.h @ 3503]
00000000`001de790 00000000`7741a01b : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00330d20 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
00000000`001de850 00000000`7741a061 : 00000000`00000014 00000000`77412094 00000000`0081d1f8 0000002c`00000001 : user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xc3
00000000`001de8b0 00000000`776af5e5 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`776836a8 00000000`00000001 : user32!_fnDWORD+0x2d
00000000`001de910 00000000`7740f5ba : 00000000`7742762b 00000000`000202cc 00000000`0081d1d0 00000000`00000001 : ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue (TrapFrame @ 00000000`001de7d8)
00000000`001de998 00000000`7742762b : 00000000`000202cc 00000000`0081d1d0 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : user32!ZwUserDestroyWindow+0xa
00000000`001de9a0 00000000`774274a5 : 00000000`000202cc 00000001`3f99b800 00000000`00000001 00000000`000202cc : user32!DialogBox2+0x2ec
00000000`001dea30 00000000`7742751a : 00000001`3fce5f00 00000000`000202cc 00000001`3f99b800 00000001`3f99b800 : user32!InternalDialogBox+0x135
00000000`001dea90 00000000`77427558 : 00000000`00000000 00000001`3f980000 00000001`3fce5f00 00000000`000202cc : user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW+0x58
00000000`001dead0 00000001`3f9a3d0b : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000070 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`001dec30 : user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamW+0x18
00000000`001deb10 00000001`3f99aca2 : 00000000`00008026 00000000`001dec20 00000000`001dec90 00000000`00008026 : MyApp_Tray!ATL::AtlAxDialogCreateT<wchar_t const * __ptr64,ATL::_AtlDialogBoxIndirectParamHelper,&DialogBoxIndirectParamW>+0xbb [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlhost.h @ 2714]
00000000`001deb60 00000001`3f995b03 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001df270 00000000`001dec90 00000000`001df270 : MyApp_Tray!ATL::CAxDialogImpl<CStatusPopup,ATL::CWindow>::DoModal+0x82 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwin.h @ 4055]
00000000`001deb90 00000001`3f9ade73 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001df270 00000000`001df168 000007ff`fffdd000 : MyApp_Tray!CDataNetWindow::ProcessWindowMessage+0x293 [d:\buildroot\26\datanow\datanow_features_fr1\sources\orca\datanet_tray\mainwnd.h @ 40]
00000000`001df000 00000000`7741c3c1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`001df2e0 00000000`00000001 : MyApp_Tray!ATL::CWindowImplBaseT<WTL::CEditT<ATL::CWindow>,ATL::CWinTraits<1442840576,0> >::WindowProc+0x83 [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlwin.h @ 3508]
00000000`001df0a0 00000000`7741c60a : 00000000`001df2d0 00000000`00330fe0 00000000`01dae740 00000000`0083bf10 : user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1ad
00000000`001df160 00000001`3f998236 : 00000001`3f9bada0 00000001`3f9bada0 00000000`00330fe0 00000000`00000000 : user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x3b5
00000000`001df1e0 00000001`3f9b22b6 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`776fdffa : MyApp_Tray!wWinMain+0x886 [d:\buildroot\26\datanow\datanow_features_fr1\sources\orca\datanet_tray\tray.cpp @ 356]
00000000`001df8b0 00000000`76f9f34d : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : MyApp_Tray!__tmainCRTStartup+0x166 [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\crtexe.c @ 547]
00000000`001df960 00000000`77692ca1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`001df990 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d
```

And it's being caused because hwnd is NULL in this ATL code:

```
template <class TBase, class TWinTraits>
LRESULT CALLBACK CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >::WindowProc(
    _In_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT uMsg,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >* pThis = (CWindowImplBaseT< TBase, TWinTraits >*)hWnd;
    // set a ptr to this message and save the old value
    _ATL_MSG msg(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    const _ATL_MSG* pOldMsg = pThis->m_pCurrentMsg;
    pThis->m_pCurrentMsg = &msg;
    // pass to the message map to process
    LRESULT lRes = 0;
    BOOL bRet = pThis->ProcessWindowMessage(pThis->m_hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, lRes, 0);
```

Comment: If you take a closer look at the call stack, the exception takes place in WTL edit control class, not the `CStatusPopup` dialog.

Comment: Hmm, so it does, so perhaps an edit control is still alive after the window dies...

Comment: I don't see the code, but it seems unlikely that the faulty edit control belongs to that modal dialog.

Comment: You're correct, it looks like I have an edit control created somewhere else that's alive and receiving messages after it should be dead...  The WTL CEditT control appears to be used in various places in the code I'm looking at.  Generally it seems to be used as a member of dialog objects and it appears that it should be cleaned up when dialogs are destroyed.

Comment: You should be able to see its `hWnd`, and so you should at least be able to identify which exactly this edit control is, what window it belongs to. Having done that, you will be able to isolate the problem reasonably.